# ARP packets are sent as IPv4 packet

Tags: arp

Is it true and why?
ARP packets are sent as IPv4 packet.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: ARP is neither IP nor TCP as it isn't encapsulated by IP nor by TCP.

Comment: WireShark says: ProtocolType: IP

Comment: ARP exists between layers 2 and 3 of the OSI model but ARP packets are not IP packets. They are not encapsulated by IP.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in this Wirshark capture image, ARP is not encapsulated by IP, so it is not an IP packet.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **no**.

ARP packets have Ethernet type `0x0806` while IPv4 has Ethernet type `0x0800`.

ARP packets do carry a protocol field indicating the protocol the resolution is related to. So the ARP packets has Ethernet type `0x0806` and inside the ARP packet is a protocol field with value `0x0800` because it is exchanging IPv4 addresses.

IPv6 has Ethernet type `0x86DD` and doesn't use ARP. Instead it uses Neighbor Discovery. It works almost the same as ARP, but ND packets are encapsulated inside ICMPv6 packets, so IPv6 only needs one Ethernet type not two like IPv4.